# probability distribution of two random processes

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

I have next statistical problem: I have a box which is empty initially. A ball is introduced in the box randomly with a given probability, $P_{in}$. After some time we count the number of balls. The probability of finding $N$ balls in the box is given by the Poisson distribution
$$P_N=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{N}}{N!},$$
being $\lambda$ the average number of balls found in the box after a time.

In the problem I have, there is a probability of introducing a ball to the box, $P_{in}$, but also to extract it, $P_{out}$. I would like to know if this probability distribution is known. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does “being $N$ the average number of balls found in the box” mean? Is it an exercise from some textbook. Would you give the reference and provide context?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have corrected this sentence which was wrong. This is a problem I found during my PhD in statistical physics (I have no reference), where I get two processes similarly to adding or extracting a ball.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the number of balls in the box being governed by a [discrete-time birth-death process](http://www.randomservices.org/random/markov/BirthDeath.html) (which is a Markov chain), with birth rate $b=P_{in}$ and death rate $a=P_{out}$.

Lets assume $a \neq b$. Then, by (8) in the link above, we have a transient chain if $a<b$, null recurrent chain if $a=b$ and a positive recurrent chain if $a>b$ with invariant distribution $f(x) = (1-a/b) (a/b)^x$.

Comment: I think the positive recurrent distribution should be f(x) = (1-b/a)(b/a)^x

Comment: While I'm on the subject: I think the positive recurrent distribution is good for predicting changes in the number of balls, if starting with a large number, but not for "empty initially."

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This problem isn't particularly well specified, but oh well.